# Look for all `highway` type `way` in certain area, using the overpass-api directly (not overpass turbo) or osmosis

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api, nominatim, osmosis, overpass-turbo

I need all `highway` type `way` in certain area, I found this query the result I want, but using **overpass-turbo** (I would like to use only overpass-api or even better only osmosis):

```
<osm-script output="json">
  <id-query {{nominatimArea:Temperley,Partido de Lomas de zamora,Buenos Aires,Argentina}} into="area"/> 
    <query type="way">
      <has-kv k="highway"/>
      <area-query from="area"/>
    </query>
  <print mode="body"/>
  <recurse type="down"/>
  <print mode="skeleton" order="quadtile"/>
</osm-script>
```

I need to perform this task from a backend hundreds of times using differents areas. So I think I should use **overpass-api** directly (not using the overpass-turbo frontend), doing a POST request here http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter .
The issue is that above query fails using overpass-api, I think because of `{{nominatimArea}}`. When I inspect the POST made for overpass-turbo, I found that the real query to overpass-api is:

```
<osm-script output="json">    
<id-query type="area" ref="3602537337" into="area"/> 
        <query type="way">
          <has-kv k="highway"/>
          <area-query from="area"/>
        </query>
      <print mode="body"/>
      <recurse type="down"/>
      <print mode="skeleton" order="quadtile"/>
    </osm-script>
```

When I run that query in overpass-api directly, I get the desired result.

As you can see, **the difference is that** `{{nominatimArea}}` **is replaced by** `type="area" ref="3602537337"`.

So, Is there a way to know that `ref="3602537337"` associated to a `{{nominatimArea}}`?

I have Nominatim installed locally, so I have the `relation id` too, Is there a way to use that id or maybe something else?

Do I need another approach to this issue?

PD: Perfect scenario for me would be to use osmosis directly but I can't understand documentation ;(  I have all the polygons I need, all names and relations ids too.

Answer (score 3):

**Backend solution (no API)**

I found a solution using just backend scripts without overpass or any other api using [osmium](https://osmcode.org/osmium-tool/manual.html#introduction) instead of osmosis.

- Download the extract you want from [geofabrik.de](https://download.geofabrik.de/) (.pbf file) or the entire planet.
- [Install osmium](https://osmcode.org/osmium-tool/manual.html#installation)
- Extract the polygon (relation id = 2537337) running `osmium getid -r -t argentina-latest.osm.pbf r2537337 -o temperley-boundary.osm` where `r2537337` is the relation id.
- Extract info inside the previous polygon running `osmium extract -p temperley-boundary.osm argentina-latest.osm.pbf -o temperley.pbf`.
- Filter highways running `osmium tags-filter temperley.pbf w/highway -o highways_in_temperley.osm.pbf`.

I also need to convert .pbf to .json or .geojson so I used [osmtogeojson](https://www.npmjs.com/package/osmtogeojson) because I'm already in a node app.

**Using Overpass API**

I found a solution in the [Overpass API wiki page](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#By_area_.28area.29)

> By convention the area id can be calculated from an existing OSM way
> by adding 2400000000 to its OSM id, or in case of a relation by adding
> 3600000000 respectively.

So, knowing the `osm_id` type `R` (relation id) you have to add 3600000000. The area, "Temperley,Partido de Lomas de zamora,Buenos Aires,Argentina" has the osm id 2537337 and it is a relation, then that number came from 3600000000 + 2537337 = 3602537337